# SQLAlchemy Flask filter query to combine results from two models

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to order a user's thanks(posts) by date_registered.

At the moment, there are two queries to get two lists, then manually combine and re-order. A user can be a giver of thank or a receiver. A thank has always a single giver, however might have multiple receivers. Therefore I have a Thank and a ThankReceivedByUser models to achive results.

```
class Thank(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    giver_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable = False)
    status = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable = False) 
    date_registered = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)

class ThankReceivedByUser(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    thank_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("thank.id"), nullable = False)
    receiver_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable = False)
    status = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable = False) 
    date_registered = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)
```

It would be great to get some hints on constructing a single query if possible.

Comment: What two lists do you mean: list of given thanks and a list of received thanks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this problem:

```
thanks = Thank.query\
    .join(ThanksReceivedByUser)\
    .filter(or_(Thank.giver_id == user.id, 
                ThankReceivedByUser.receiver_id == user.id))\
    .order_by(Thank.date_registered).all()
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to combine thanks given and received by a user in a single query. If so, you need to [`UNION`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union) two queries, one of which selects given thanks, while another received ones. Then you can order the results of this combined query. Here's how your query would look like:

```py
# user_id contains a value of some user's id.
given_q = db.session.query(Thank).filter_by(giver_id=user_id)
received_q = db.session.query(Thank).join(ThankReceivedByUser).\
    filter(ThankReceivedByUser.receiver_id == user_id)
q = given_q.union(received_q).order_by(Thank.date_registered)
```